# Oozie Subworkflow containing fork node hangs

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow which makes use of sub-workflow node. The sub-workflow contains action nodes out of which few are using fork mechanism. On triggering the parent workflow, it can be seen that all the jobs/nodes just before the fork (from sub flow) execute perfectly but the nodes within fork are stuck in PREP state.What is even worse is I am unable to kill the job by using Oozie kill command for both the workflows ( parent and sub )
*Hadoop Version : CDH3u5

Oozie client build version: 2.3.2-cdh3u5*

My best guess is that there is a bug in Oozie when it encounters Subworkflow and fork within that workflow. Please suggest ways to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To kill oozie job use this command:

```
oozie job -kill ID
```

Make sure you have enough map slots in your hadoop. Each workflow, sub-workflow and forks allocate one map slot. Each action also allocates at least one map slot. You could be in deadlock state.